Prove that there is a unique positive real number $m$ with two required properties using limit.
I have a problem proving the existential part for the following theorem:
There is a unique positive real number $m$ that has the following two properties:
(a) For every positive real number $x$, $\frac{x}{x+1} < m$.
(b) If $y$ is any positive real number with the property that for every positive real number $x$, $\frac{x}{x+1} < y$, then $m \le y$.
While it's obvious that $m = 1$ and (a) can be proved easily, proving (b) is a challenge for me.
The method which I can come up with right now is to use limit to prove (b). I observe that $\frac{z}{z+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{z+1}$, so $\lim_{z \to \infty} \left(1 -\frac{1}{z+1}\right) = 1$. This fact along with the fact that for an arbitrary positive real number $x$, $\frac{x}{x+1} < 1$ and the assumption that for arbitrary real numbers $x$ and $y$, $\frac{x}{x+1} < y$ suggest that $\frac{x}{x+1} < 1 \le y$.
The problem is I don't know whether I can use limit in such a way to prove (b) or not.

This question is similar to: Proof of a limit inequality. If $\forall n\in\Bbb N,a_n\le y$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, then $a\le y$. (Apply this to $a_n=\frac n{n+1}$ and $a=1$.)

Why don't you simply use a proof by contradiction?
Imagine an $y$, smaller than $1$ (let's call it $1-\varepsilon$). Then you search for a value $x$ ($x(\varepsilon)$ to be exact) for which $\frac{x}{x+1}>1-\varepsilon$ (it shouldn't be too hard to find, I believe it's something like $x > 1/\varepsilon - 1$), and your statement is proven.
